# How can I draw a quadrilateral using a mouse in matplotlib and take the vertices of the quadrilateral as an input into a python function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to draw a quadrilateral on this plot using my mouse and after that, I want the coordinates of these quadrilaterals as an input into my python function.

Image:

[image]

This green dot is the first vertex and I want to point to three more vertices of the quadrilateral using a mouse click. While creating these four green dots I also want to draw a red line from one green dot to another green dot so that it takes a quadrilateral shape. Please help me.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import StringVar

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("Quadrilaterals Plot")
root.minsize(600, 400)
root.maxsize(800, 600)
fig = plt.figure()

frame = Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
labl = Label(frame, text="I WANT TO DRAW:", font=("Arial Bold", 10)).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)


def graph():
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xlim(-8, 8)
    plt.ylim(-8, 8)
    plt.show()



r = StringVar()
r.set("square")

frame1 = Frame(root).grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5)
Radiobutton(root, text="SQUARE", variable=r, value="square").grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5)


frame2 = Frame(root).grid(row=5, column=0, pady=5)
Radiobutton(root, text="RECTANGLE", variable=r, value="rectangle").grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)


frame3 = Frame(root).grid(row=7, column=0, pady=5)
Radiobutton(root, text="PARALLELOGRAM", variable=r, value="parallelogram").grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5)


frame4 = Frame(root).grid(row=9, column=0, pady=5)
Radiobutton(root, text="RHOMBUS", variable=r, value="rhombus").grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5)

frame5 = Frame(root).grid(row=11, column=0, pady=5)
button = Button(frame4, text="Plot on Graph", command=graph).grid(row=13, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
end = Button(frame4, text="END", command=quit).grid(row=13, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)



def first(p1):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot(p1[0], p1[1])
    plt.plot(p1[0], p1[1], 'go')
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xlim(-8, 8)
    plt.ylim(-8, 8)
    plt.show()

def two(p2):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot(p2[0], p2[1])
    plt.plot(p2[0], p2[1], 'go')
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xlim(-8, 8)
    plt.ylim(-8, 8)
    plt.show()


def third(p3):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot(p3[0], p3[1])
    plt.plot(p3[0], p3[1], 'go')
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xlim(-8, 8)
    plt.ylim(-8, 8)
    plt.show()


def four(p4):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot(p4[0], p4[1])
    plt.plot(p4[0], p4[1], 'go')
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xlim(-8, 8)
    plt.ylim(-8, 8)
    plt.show()


coords = []


def onclick1(event):
    global ix1, iy1
    ix1, iy1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
    global coords
    coords.append(ix1)
    coords.append(iy1)
    if len(coords) == 2:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
    p1 = [coords[0], coords[1]]
    first(p1)


def onclick2(event):
    global ix2, iy2
    ix2, iy2 = event.xdata, event.ydata
    global coords
    coords.append(ix2)
    coords.append(iy2)
    if len(coords) == 4:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(did)
    p2 = [coords[0], coords[1]]
    two(p2)


def onclick3(event):
    global ix3, iy3
    ix3, iy3 = event.xdata, event.ydata
    global coords
    coords.append(ix3)
    coords.append(iy3)
    if len(coords) == 6:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(eid)
    p3 = [coords[0], coords[1]]
    third(p3)


def onclick4(event):
    global ix4, iy4
    ix4, iy4 = event.xdata, event.ydata
    global coords
    coords.append(ix4)
    coords.append(iy4)
    if len(coords) == 8:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(fid)
    p4 = [coords[0], coords[1]]
    four(p4)


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick1)
did = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick2)
eid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick3)
fid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick4)


def quit():
    root.destroy()
    exit()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how did you draw it? To draw it you would have to have coordinates. Yoi should keep them in some variable.

Answer (score 0):

The plt.ginput() function is better suited to solve your problem.

> Blocking call to interact with a figure.

> Wait until the user clicks n times on the figure, and return the coordinates of each click in a list.
> [matplotlib.pyplot.ginput](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.html)

Cleaned up your code a bit. Coordinates to process in xy_array.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import StringVar
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon


def graph(r):

    global xy_array
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.title(f'Select 4 points by clicking \n on the left mouse button to draw a {r.get()}.', fontsize=12)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xlim(-8, 8)
    plt.ylim(-8, 8)

# Made the grid more often on the chart.
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.grid(which='major', color='k', linewidth=1)
    ax.grid(which='minor', color='k', linestyle=':')

# The plt.ginput() function is better suited to solve your problem.
    xy_array = np.array(plt.ginput(4, timeout=-1))
    ph = Polygon(xy_array, facecolor='none', edgecolor='purple', linewidth=3)
    ax.add_patch(ph)

    plt.title('Thank you! Your result is being processed.\n You can close the window and try again.', fontsize=12)
    plt.show()


def quit():
    root.destroy()


# For the coordinates of the constructed figure.
xy_array = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("Quadrilaterals Plot")
root.minsize(600, 400)
root.maxsize(800, 600)

r = StringVar()
r.set("square")

# To call a function with an argument.
call_graph = partial(graph, r)

# For shorthand window formatting.
font = ("Arial Bold", 12)
options = {'sticky': 'w', 'padx': '20', 'ipadx': '20'}

lbl = Label(root, text="I WANT TO DRAW:", font=("Arial Bold", 14, "bold"))
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

Radiobutton(root, text="SQUARE", font=font, variable=r, value="square").grid(row=1, column=0, **options)
Radiobutton(root, text="RECTANGLE", font=font, variable=r, value="rectangle").grid(row=2, column=0, **options)
Radiobutton(root, text="PARALLELOGRAM", font=font, variable=r, value="parallelogram").grid(row=3, column=0, **options)
Radiobutton(root, text="RHOMBUS", font=font, variable=r, value="rhombus").grid(row=4, column=0, **options)

btn = Button(root, text="Plot on Graph", font=font, command=call_graph)
btn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, ipadx=20)

end = Button(root, text="END", font=font, command=quit)
end.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, ipadx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

There is another problem, if the points are placed crosswise, then the figure will be drawn with intersecting sides. You can simply swap any two adjacent coordinates in xy_array to draw a convex figure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you explain to me one more thing, how can I take those coordinates as input to a function? Like if there is a function called square and I want all these four coordinates as input to the square function when I click on the mouse.

Comment: @Sachin Kumar Just using a pure button command, you can't pass arguments to the function. But there are different workarounds: the partial function, the bind method, and the lambda function. Choose what you like best.

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually the above problem is solved and I'm getting four points as a tuple; p1 = (2, 2), p2 = (2, 6), p3 = (6, 6) and p4 = (2, 6) after selecting four points on the graph. I want these four tuple points to pass in 4 different type of functions: isSquare(p1, p2, p3, p4), isRectangle(p1, p2, p3, p4), isParallelogram(p1, p2, p3, p4) and isRhombus(p1, p2, p3, p4) to check if its a square, rectangle, parallelogram or rhombus. I'm not able to do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since tkinter and matplotlib are two different threads, a queue is used to transfer data between them.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import StringVar
from functools import partial
import queue

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon





def graph(r, q):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.title(f'Select 4 points by clicking \n on the left mouse button to draw a {r.get()}.', fontsize=12)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xlim(-8, 8)
    plt.ylim(-8, 8)

    # Made the grid more often on the chart.
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.grid(which='major', color='k', linewidth=1)
    ax.grid(which='minor', color='k', linestyle=':')

    # The plt.ginput() function is better suited to solve your problem.
    list_xy = np.array(plt.ginput(4, timeout=-1)).tolist()

    # We put the received list of coordinates in the queue.
    q.put(list_xy)

    ph = Polygon(list_xy, facecolor='none', edgecolor='purple', linewidth=3)
    ax.add_patch(ph)
    plt.title('Thank you! Your result is being processed.\n You can close the window and try again.', fontsize=12)
    plt.show()


def quit_root():
    root.destroy()


def is_square(args):
    print(f'square {args}')


def is_rectangle(args):
    print(f'rectangle {args}')


def is_parallelogram(args):
    print(f'parallelogram {args}')


def is_rhombus(args):
    print(f'rhombus {args}')



def fun(r, q):
    # We get the coordinates of the polygon from the queue.
    p = q.get()
    choice = r.get()
    if choice == 'square':
        is_square(p)
    elif choice == 'rectangle':
        is_rectangle(p)
    elif choice == 'parallelogram':
        is_parallelogram(p)
    elif choice == 'rhombus':
        is_rhombus(p)
    else:
        print("mistake")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("Quadrilaterals Plot")
root.minsize(600, 400)
root.maxsize(800, 600)

r = StringVar()
r.set("square")

# We create a queue for transferring data from matplotlib to tkinter.
q = queue.Queue()

# To call a function with an argument.
call_graph = partial(graph, r, q)
call_fun = partial(fun, r, q)

# For shorthand window formatting.
font = ("Arial Bold", 12)
options = {'sticky': 'w', 'padx': '20', 'ipadx': '20'}

lbl = Label(root, text="I WANT TO DRAW:", font=("Arial Bold", 14, "bold"))
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

Radiobutton(root, text="SQUARE", font=font, variable=r, value="square").grid(row=1, column=0, **options)
Radiobutton(root, text="RECTANGLE", font=font, variable=r, value="rectangle").grid(row=2, column=0, **options)
Radiobutton(root, text="PARALLELOGRAM", font=font, variable=r, value="parallelogram").grid(row=3, column=0, **options)
Radiobutton(root, text="RHOMBUS", font=font, variable=r, value="rhombus").grid(row=4, column=0, **options)

btn = Button(root, text="Plot on Graph", font=font, command=call_graph)
btn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, ipadx=20)

end = Button(root, text="END", font=font, command=quit_root)
end.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, ipadx=20)

fun = Button(root, text="FUN", font=font, command=call_fun)
fun.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=20, pady=5, ipadx=20)


root.mainloop()
```

For correct operation, the program still needs to check whether the queue is empty?